# HTML language and forms

Tags: javascript, html, list, forms, html-select

I have a problem with an HTML form. I had in mind to let the site visitor choose a place, and choosing one of the 2 places in Sicily would redirect him to a specific web page, one different to the other based on the place chosen (and momentarily the 2 redirect files are in the same folder as the main file, and are "Book=Catania" and "Book=Mondello").

I used `<input type = "text">` with some "list" suggestions. For the answer I used a JavaScript script with the if condition.

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function checkCheckBox (f) {
if (f.mondello.checked == true)
{
window.location.href = 'book=mondello.html';
return false;
}
if (f.catania.checked == true)
{
window.location.href = 'book=catania.html';
return false;
}}
</script>
<form action = "" method = "POST" onsubmit = "return checkCheckBox (this)">
<fieldset>
<br/>
<legend> Indicates the place </legend>
<input type = "text" size = "40" list = "places">
<datalist id = "places">
  <option value = "Mondello, PA, Sicily" name = "mondello">
  <option value = "Catania, CT, Sicily" name = "catania">
</datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `book=catania.html`. That's not a URL... Try doing `./book=catania.html` .  Although having = inside URLs doesn't feel right to me, unless there in query params.

Comment: Add `onchange` event listener to the datalist or select list, set the value option attribute to match your redirections files, then you just have to get the value of the selected option to forward.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a form the way it was meant to be used.

You've got a lot of code that isn't actually helping. By using a text based select drop down you can actually enter anything you want into the field. This could cause 404s on your site.

I've changed your input into a select, with the name book. It's hard to show in stack snippets, but when this submits the form, it will navigate to the current page ( to change add an action on the form element) with the parameter `book=<selected option>`. You could add back in the post method which would hide this from the URL, however that would make this difficult to link to a friend.

The only JS you need is to force the form to submit on select change. You'll want to make the selectors more specific to your scenario, but otherwise that's all you need for JS.

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.querySelector('form').submit();
})
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <select name="book">
      <option disabled selected>Select one</option>
      <option value="mondello">Mondello, PA, Sicily</option>
      <option value="catania">Catania, CT, Sicily</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
```